# change underline line colour when hovering between menu item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery, css, megamenu

I have mega menu in sharepoint 2013 build using managed metadata. I would like to find out how i can add different colour of line in the top menu when it hover between top menu item using jquery.

```
var i = 0;

var ul = null;
jQuery("div #zz12_TopNavigationMenu ul").each(function () {
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        ul = this.id.toString();
        return false;
    }
});
ulItems = jQuery("ul#" + ul);
```

Comment: You might want to read up on the ``index`` parameter of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create javascript with content below then link the javascript to masterpage

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#DeltaTopNavigation>div>ul>li>ul');


divs[0].style.borderTop='blue';
divs[1].style.borderTop='red';
divs[2].style.borderTop='green';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `hover` selector.

```
a:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

So for the sharepoint menu, it would be something like:

```
div #zz12_TopNavigationMenu ul a:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Reference - [CSS hover selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)